# Why does changing the margin and padding by a value of one shift all of my buttons?

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I was just learning some HTML and CSS and was given an exercise which requires me to make three buttons that expand vertically on hover. In my version of the code, hovering over one button shifts the other buttons over. However, in the instructor's code, his `margin-left` `margin-right` `padding-left` `padding-right` values differ by 1px, and his buttons do not shift at all. I was considering creating a container but he did it without one and I was wondering how exactly does 1px make that big of a difference?

My code:

```css
            .margin-and-padding {
                padding-top: 9px;
                padding-bottom: 9px;
                padding-right: 16px;
                padding-left: 16px;
        
                margin-right: 11px;
                margin-left: 11px;
                
                border: none;
                background-color: green;
                color: white;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 15px;
                transition: margin 0.2s, padding 0.2s;
            }
        
            .margin-and-padding:hover {
                padding-left: 25px;
                padding-right: 25px;
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-left: 0px;
            }
```

```html
 <button class="margin-and-padding">One</button>
        <button class="margin-and-padding">Two</button>
        <button class="margin-and-padding">Three</button>
```

His code:

```css
        .stretch-button {
          background-color: green;
          color: white;
          border: none;
          font-size: 18px;
          padding-top: 8px;
          padding-bottom: 8px;
          cursor: pointer;
      
          padding-left: 15px;
          padding-right: 15px;
          margin-left: 10px;
          margin-right: 10px;
      
          transition: padding 0.15s,
            margin 0.15s;
        }
      
        .stretch-button:hover {
          padding-left: 25px;
          padding-right: 25px;
          margin-left: 0px;
          margin-right: 0px;
        }
```

```html
<button class="stretch-button">
        One
      </button>
      <button class="stretch-button">
        Two
      </button>
      <button class="stretch-button">
        Three
      </button>
```

Could anyone try this out and let me know?
Also sorry for any formatting issues, this is my first time posting.

Comment: well he has taken that into account : 15 + 10 = 25, in your code 16 + 11 = 27, so there is 2 extra pixels

Comment: the sum need to remain the same, so you add 1px to margin and remove 1px from padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take just `padding-left` in both examples, in your example `padding-left: 16px;` + `margin-left: 11px;` = 27px and on hover becomes `padding-left: 25px;` + `margin-left: 0px;` = 25px, which will make them shift 2px